# Hebrew in ModernCV failing with TeXLive 2019 XeLaTeX

Tags: moderncv, overleaf, texlive-2019

The following MWE fails when run with TexLive 2019. It works with TeXLive 2017 and 2018.

```
\documentclass[english,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\firstname{J}
\lastname{D}
\title{T}

\newfontfamily\englishfont[Language=English,Script=Latin]{Latin Modern Sans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle{}{}

Lorem ipsum and such

\texthebrew{לורם איפסום}
\end{document}
```

Using the overleaf engine (if that is of any importance). The example here is with DejaVu, but the problem also arises (in 2019) using `David CLM`, `Simple CLM`, or `Miriam Mono CLM` (works in 2018).

The error I get is(dunno how much this means in Latex)

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font DejaVuSans(0) does not cont
ain the "Hebrew" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily comm
and.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but you should not be using  `fontenc` in the same document as Unicode.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: removed fontenc (and indeed it made no difference) added the log containing the error (though I doubt it is helpful in latex). I am using Overleaf. When I define the Tex Live version to be 2018 or 2017 it works perfectly. With 2019 it fails with the error given

Comment: Sounds like it’s using a bad version of the font. Does selecting a different font work?

Comment: Tried other fonts. Again, all work in 2018, none work in 2019. Changed the title and edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem: It is not a bug, it's a feature. Polyglossia in TeXLive 2019 simply works better.

The documentclass has a sans option, but no sans font is defined for Hebrew. Replacing `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{}` with `\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{}` solved the "problem".

In TeXLive 2017 (and 2018), The `documentclass` definition only applied to the default (English) font. If `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{}` was defined and then `\texthebrew{}` command used, then the default defined font would indeed be used.

In TexLive 2019 since sans option was declared, when `\texthebrew{}` was called polyglossia looked for the sans family font. Because, as defined in the `documentclass`, the document should be in sans unless otherwise defined.

The following MWE demonstrates the difference.

```
\documentclass[english,sans]{article} %<--- The document default is defined as sans

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{David CLM} %<--- notice David
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{DejaVu Sans}%<--- notice Sans


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum and such

\textsf{\texthebrew{עברית בסנס}}

\texthebrew{עברית רגיל}
\end{document}
```

The output with TexLive 2017 is the following:

[image]

The output with TexLive 2019 is this:

[image]

The MWE in the question did not have a sans font defined, so I got an error.